# Phoenix plug to check for required query param

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following controller:

```
defmodule Campaigns.CampaignController do
  use Campaigns.Web, :controller

  alias Campaigns.Campaign
  alias Campaigns.ApiParams

  plug :ensure_account_id

  def index(conn, %{"account_id" => account_id}) do
    query = from c in Campaign, where: [account_id: ^account_id]
    render(conn, "index.json", campaigns: Repo.all(query))
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id, "account_id" => account_id}) do
    query = from c in Campaign, where: [id: ^id, account_id: ^account_id]
    render(conn, "show.json", campaign: Repo.one(query))
  end

  defp ensure_account_id(conn, _) do
    cs = ApiParams.changeset(%ApiParams{}, conn.params)
    case cs do
      %{:params => %{"account_id" => account_id}, :valid? => true} ->
        conn
      _ ->
        conn
        |> put_status(400)
        |> render(conn, "400.json", "account_id is missing")
    end
  end
end
```

I am wanting to ensure that the `account_id` is present in the request made to each endpoint in this controller. The error in the console I am getting is

```
[error] #PID<0.403.0> running Campaigns.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/campaigns/1
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.Controller.render/4
```

But I have a `render("400.json"` method in my ErrorView.ex file.

Here is my `ErrorView.ex` file

```
defmodule Campaigns.ErrorView do
  use Campaigns.Web, :view

  def render("404.html", _assigns) do
    "Page not found"
  end

  def render("500.html", _assigns) do
    "Internal server error"
  end

  def render("400.json", %{"message" => error}) do
    %{error: error}
  end

  # In case no render clause matches or no
  # template is found, let's render it as 500
  def template_not_found(_template, assigns) do
    render "500.html", assigns
  end
end
```

Comment: `put_status/2` return `conn`so you have to remove the `conn` in your `render` function

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie to Phoenix/Elixir, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
defp ensure_account_id(conn, _) do
cs = ApiParams.changeset(%ApiParams{}, conn.params)
case cs do
  %{:params => %{"account_id" => account_id}, :valid? => true} ->
    conn
  _ ->
    conn
    |> put_status(400)
    |> render("400.json", message: "account_id is missing") # remove the `conn` here
end
```

end

Comment: Ah, ok! When I do that I receive the error of [error] #PID<0.547.0> running Campaigns.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/campaigns/1
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.Controller.render/3

Comment: Edited.The third param should be a keyword or a map.

Comment: I added my ErrorView in the original question and I changed my `render` call to match what you have.

Comment: `[error] #PID<0.681.0> running Campaigns.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/campaigns/1
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError) Could not render "400.json" for Campaigns.CampaignView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "web/templates/campaign". No templates were compiled for this module.`

Comment: Oh i see.You should define a `Campaigns.CampaignView` module with your `render` function in there or you can specify your ErrorView in your `render` function.

Comment: How about `|> render(Campaigns.ErrorView, "400.json", %{"message" => "account_id is missing"})`?

Comment: With that, I get this: `[debug] ** (Phoenix.ActionClauseError) bad request to Campaigns.CampaignController.show, no matching action clause to process request`

Comment: change your `render` function like this `render("400.json", %{message: error})`